# iterate an array inside an array and display the playerId, playerName and playerCategory

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, reactjs

**update 3:**

found the answer after debugging. Providing the solution below

```
let values = {
  "sportsEntitties": [{
      "sportsEntityId": 30085585,
      "sportsEntityName": "490349903434903490",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "7878787878",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "erierioerioerioioe",
      "targetData": [{
          "playerName": "490349903434903490",
          "playerCategory": "hjuwerwewkwjke",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489823",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        },
        {
          "playerName": "490349903434903490",
          "playerCategory": "hjuwerwewkwjke",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489823",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        },
        {
          "playerName": "490349903434903490",
          "playerCategory": "hjuwerwewkwjke",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489823",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sportsEntityId": 30077252,
      "sportsEntityName": "uieruieuieruiuier",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "7878787878",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "erierioerioerioioe",
      "targetData": [{
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783484818,
          "playerName": "eruieruiiererui",
          "playerCategory": "uuiweruiwerweruiwfuiw",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "347834783478347834787834783478347878347-10-30"
        },
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493294,
          "playerName": "990we9090we90we90",
          "playerCategory": "uuiweruiwerweruiwfuiw",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-06-30"
        },
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493779,
          "playerName": "uieruieuieruiuier",
          "playerCategory": "hjuwerwewkwjke",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sportsEntityId": 30085115,
      "sportsEntityName": "cvccvcvcvcvcv",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "2010-06-30",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
      "targetData": [{
        "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493279,
        "playerName": "jkcvjkcdjkcvj",
        "playerCategory": "uuiweruiwerweruiwfuiw",
        "playerTaxId": "27-2695112",
        "relationshipStartDate": "2010-06-30"
      }]
    }

  ],
  "corporateEntityId": "wewewe",
  "corporateEntityName": "wewewewe"
}

let sportsExpnasionHeading = [];


sportsExpnasionHeading = values.sportsEntitties.map(obj => {
  return {
    sportsEntityName: obj.sportsEntityName,
    targetData: obj.targetData.map(obj =>
      ({
        label: `${obj.playerName} | ${obj.playerCategory}`,

        value: obj.playerTaxId,
        category: obj.playerCategory,
        checked: true
      })
    )
  }
});

console.log("sportsExpnasionHeading--->", sportsExpnasionHeading);
```

**update2:**

- now my data is moved inside targetData array. so my json structure changed.
- I used same code and iterated but still not getting the value.
- can you tell me how to fetch playerName and playerCategory

```or-tag-here
const results = Object.values(others).map(obj => {
            return obj[0].playerName + '|' + obj[0].playerCategory
        });

{
  "sportsEntitties": [
    {
      "sportsEntityId": 30085585,
      "sportsEntityName": "490349903434903490",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "7878787878",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "erierioerioerioioe",
      "targetData": [
        {
          "playerName": "490349903434903490",
          "playerCategory": "Group",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489823",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sportsEntityId": 30077252,
      "sportsEntityName": "uieruieuieruiuier",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "7878787878",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "erierioerioerioioe",
      "targetData": [
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783484818,
          "playerName": "eruieruiiererui",
          "playerCategory": "Facility",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "347834783478347834787834783478347878347-10-30"
        },
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493294,
          "playerName": "990we9090we90we90",
          "playerCategory": "Facility",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-06-30"
        },
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493779,
          "playerName": "uieruieuieruiuier",
          "playerCategory": "Group",
          "playerTaxId": "789347893489348934893489760",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-07-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sportsEntityId": 30085115,
      "sportsEntityName": "cvccvcvcvcvcv",
      "sportsEntityStartDate": "2010-06-30",
      "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
      "targetData": [
        {
          "playerId": 3478347834783478347878347834783478783493279,
          "playerName": "jkcvjkcdjkcvj",
          "playerCategory": "Facility",
          "playerTaxId": "27-2695112",
          "relationshipStartDate": "2010-06-30"
        }
      ]
    }

  ],
  "corporateEntityId": "wewewe",
  "corporateEntityName": "wewewewe"
}
```

**update1:**

- suppose if we have more arrays inside an array, can we iterate without giving index.
- Can you please let me know since it will helpme during complex data

```or-tag-here
{
            "sportsEntitties": [
                {
                    "sportsEntityId": 23232323,
                    "sportsEntityName": "wewewewewe",
                    "sportsEntityStartDate": "ewewwewewe",
                    "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "bunessEntityProviders": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],
                    "fddfjkjkdfjkdf": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],
                    "a": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],
                    "bc": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],
                     "de": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],
                     "jkljkllk": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ],

                }
            ],
                "corporateEntityId": "2323232323",
                    "corporateEntityName": "ssdsdsd"
        }
```

- I am trying to iterate an array inside an array and display the playerId, playerName and playerCategory.
- when I do first map I am getting the value at
  `console.log('bunessEntityProvidersValues values ---->', bunessEntityProvidersValues);`
- but when I do next map inside an array I am getting undefined.
  `console.log('combinedEntityProvidersValues values ---->', combinedEntityProvidersValues);`
- can you tell me how to fix it using map method
- I debugged but still I am not able to find out.

**sample data:**

```or-tag-here
{
            "sportsEntitties": [
                {
                    "sportsEntityId": 23232323,
                    "sportsEntityName": "wewewewewe",
                    "sportsEntityStartDate": "ewewwewewe",
                    "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "bunessEntityProviders": [
                        {
                            "playerId": 23232323232323,
                            "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
                            "playerCategory": "Facility",
                            "playerTaxId": "3233223",
                            "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
                "corporateEntityId": "2323232323",
                    "corporateEntityName": "ssdsdsd"
        }
```

**code snippet:**

```or-tag-here
let bunessEntityProvidersValues = [];
let combinedEntityProvidersValues; //= [];



bunessEntityProvidersValues = values.data.sportsEntitties.map(obj => {
    return obj.bunessEntityProviders
})
console.log('bunessEntityProvidersValues values ---->', bunessEntityProvidersValues);
combinedEntityProvidersValues = bunessEntityProvidersValues.map(obj => {
    return obj.playerName + '|' + obj.playerCategory
})
console.log('combinedEntityProvidersValues values ---->', combinedEntityProvidersValues);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `[ 'undefined|undefined' ]` for your code is because, when you run [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `values.data.sportsEntitties`, it actually returns you the results in a new array, with each element being the result of that callback function you have passed in. Thus, `bunessEntityProvidersValues` is actually a nested array, since you are specifically returning `bunessEntityProviders`, which contains an array.

You just need to select index `0` of `bunessEntityProvidersValues`, which is an array of array.

```
const combinedEntityProvidersValues = bunessEntityProvidersValues[0].map(obj => {
  return obj.playerName + '|' + obj.playerCategory
});
```

Here is the full demo. You may run it to look at the printed results.

```js
const values = {
  "sportsEntitties": [{
    "sportsEntityId": 23232323,
    "sportsEntityName": "wewewewewe",
    "sportsEntityStartDate": "ewewwewewe",
    "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
    "bunessEntityProviders": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }]
  }],
  "corporateEntityId": "2323232323",
  "corporateEntityName": "ssdsdsd"
}

const bunessEntityProvidersValues = values.sportsEntitties.map(obj => {
  return obj.bunessEntityProviders
});
//console.log(bunessEntityProvidersValues);

const combinedEntityProvidersValues = bunessEntityProvidersValues[0].map(obj => {
  return obj.playerName + '|' + obj.playerCategory
});
console.log(combinedEntityProvidersValues);
```

---

EDIT: This is how we can solve the problem from your updated data. Basically, we make use of the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to carry out [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). First, we remove the unwanted properties such as  `sportsEntityId`, `sportsEntityName`, `sportsEntityStartDate`, `sportsEntityEndDate`, and store the rest into a new object called `others`. Then, we iterate through it to print the required output.

```js
const values = {
  "sportsEntitties": [{
    "sportsEntityId": 23232323,
    "sportsEntityName": "wewewewewe",
    "sportsEntityStartDate": "ewewwewewe",
    "sportsEntityEndDate": "9999-12-31",
    "bunessEntityProviders": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],
    "fddfjkjkdfjkdf": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],
    "a": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],
    "bc": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],
    "de": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],
    "jkljkllk": [{
      "playerId": 23232323232323,
      "playerName": "sdssdsdsd",
      "playerCategory": "Facility",
      "playerTaxId": "3233223",
      "relationshipStartDate": "sdsdsdsdsd"
    }],

  }],
  "corporateEntityId": "2323232323",
  "corporateEntityName": "ssdsdsd"
}

const {
  sportsEntityId,
  sportsEntityName,
  sportsEntityStartDate,
  sportsEntityEndDate,
  ...others
} = values.sportsEntitties[0];

const results = Object.values(others).map(obj => {
  return obj[0].playerName + '|' + obj[0].playerCategory
});
/* 
const results = Object.values(others).map(list => {
  return list.map(obj => {
    return obj.playerName + '|' + obj.playerCategory
   })
}); 
*/

console.log(results);
```

Comment: - thanks for your reply, suppose if we have more arrays inside an array, can we iterate without giving index like[0].
-  Can you please let me know since it will help me during complex data. **Updated the question with complex data**

Comment: I looked at the array.map tutorial, but didnt understand this line -> _it actually returns you the results in a new array, with each element being the result of that callback function you have passed in_ can you tell me in my code which is **callback**, can you explain by giving comments in the code

Comment: @zizi Yes, definitely. Just to check, you want to print all `obj.playerName` and `obj.playerCategory` on your final output, right?

Comment: Also, I have seen your updated data. Are you sure that is the right one? You seem to have repeated `bunessEntityProviders` twice. Also, the added properties `a`, `bc`, etc are all separate properties.

Comment: hey I updated the data by mistake I have put bunessEntityProviders twice. Yeah **a, b** are separate properties. Updated the data again,this will help you to see the entire json structure.

Comment: I am thinking that we create a copy of the original object, and remove the 'unwanted' properties such as "sportsEntityId", "sportsEntityName", "sportsEntityStartDate", and "sportsEntityEndDate". Then we iterate though it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192384/discussion-between-wentjun-and-zi-zi).

Comment: hey is it possible to avoid the numbers 0, so that we can dont want to hard code the index everytime :( `obj[0]`

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through it using .map(). I have updated it within that block of code, but I have commented it out. You can check it out

Comment: hey is it possible to avoid the hard coding index value like this `sportsEntitties[0]`, can you remove this properties too `corporateEntityId corporateEntityName`

Comment: hey sorry my json structure changed, updated the structure in the question. can you please help me. Used your code and changed the key but still not working :(